# Finding google scholar page of a journal

Tags: google-scholar

Some journals have a google scholar page where you can see how many of their published articles got cited and their h-index.

Example: [Scholar page of Advanced Journal of Science and Engineering](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=FeHjTx8AAAAJ&hl=en)

How is it possible to find the page for a specific journal (except clicking on the link they sometimes provide themselves on their website)?

Comment: It looks to me like this journal is posing as an author.  Probably Google would say this should not be happening.

Answer (score 4):

The basic principle is that Google Scholar pages are for **authors**; it is **not for journals**. This is not always the case that a journal will create a Google Scholar page. If it does, it is posing itself as an author (as commented by @Anonymous Physicist). So, the example that you have given is very unusual.

However, if you are interested in articles from a specific journal, you could use the *advanced search option* in Google Scholar and enter the journal name in "Return articles published in" textbox (in my example: I am interested in articles published in the Machine Learning Journal).[image]